# How do I format Landscape and Portrait images to the same height in SwiftUI?

Tags: image, formatting, swiftui

Can anyone please point me to an example where I can dynamically format two images, one in landscape and one in portrait to be of similar heights as highlighted in red below?

I have tried using GeometryReader, but that keeps adding padding to the entire view.

[image: Example 1]

```
struct IcvImageLayout2: View {
    var images: [UIImage] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(uiImage: images[0])
                .resizable()
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .scaledToFit()
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .clipped()
                .shadow(radius: 10).frame(height: IsPortrait(image: images[0]) ? images[0].size.height * 0.75 : images[0].size.height)
                
            Image(uiImage: images[1])
                .resizable()
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .scaledToFit()
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .clipped()
                .shadow(radius: 10).frame(height: IsPortrait(image: images[1]) ? images[1].size.height * 0.75 : images[1].size.height)
                
        }
    }
    
    func IsPortrait(image: UIImage) -> Bool {
        if(image.size.height > image.size.width) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify "to the same" *which* height?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I want the two above images to be the same height as like the two pictures on the bottom in the red circle. Above is what I get, below is what I want. I could force it by placing .frame(height: 200) on the HStack and they are the same height, but then it will stay very small on an iPad.